# Am I using tf.control_dependencies from Tensorflow correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My understanding of using the below line of code is that this prevents needing to call multiple session runs.

```
with tf.control_dependencies([]):
```

For example, if we have dependent computations, instead of doing sess.run(op1) followed by sess.run(op2), you can simply execute:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([op1]):
    op2 = tf.assign(...)
```

followed by sess.run(op2). Is my understanding correct, or should it not be used for this?

Comment: does `op1` depend on `op0`? I mean do `op0` changes some values in the computation graph that lead to `op1`?

Comment: Ignore the edit with op0